# BOM couldn't extract the archive. exception in initialising pkpass with the pass url which is generated using passkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook, passkit, mashape

When trying to display the pass within my app using the following code, I am getting the error "BOM could not extract the archive. PKpass signature missing exception constantly". Please help me to get ride of this exception.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *passData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl: url];
PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:passData error:&err];
```

I am using Xcode 5.2 for the development and mashape to generate passes.

Comment: Can you give the URL that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your question relates to the [PassKit API](https://www.mashape.com/passkit/passkit) on Mashape, you need to append .pkpass to the end to the URL that is returned from the issue request.

The raw URL delivers a contextual response depending on whether or not it is being called from a Passbook capable browser (try accessing the URL via Firefox on on an Android device).

In your case, `[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl: url];` is receiving a HTML response which is causing PKPass to complain that it cannot extract the archive, and subsequently cannot find a signature.

Appending `.pkpass` to the URL forces the API to deliver the raw .pkpass bundle.

So if your response is:

```
{
  "success"        : true,
  "serial"         : "7114189133818574",
  "url"            : "https://r.pass.is/b93NuXKuX1Tj",
  "passbookSerial" : "1fBHoUz9zOOk0yGs47wDC",
  "shareID"        : "2HcFlmRLblKdQZsa4W9zkc",
  "uniqueID"       : "b93NuXKuX1Tj"
}
```

`urlString` should be `https://r.pass.is/b93NuXKuX1Tj.pkpass`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the update url of the pass through mashape?

Comment: It's better to use the update method using the uniqueID (PassID) returned from your issue request.  For security you can have your App post to a script on your server that will then pass the update request through to the Mashape.

Comment: Is it possible to receive PKPass notification when my app is in background? For instance, if my coupon rewards changes(by scanning the QR code) my app has to update its database with the changed reward even if it is in background. I think its possible, if some thread is listening to PKPass notification forever in the background but apple doesn't encourage to run a task in background forever. So any other alternate suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just do a quick read of the PKPass Library whenever your app re-enters the foreground.  Ideally, you should not rely on the pass as the source of truth.  Better to have your app call back to your database to determine the status of the pass, compare it against the pass library and if necessary, request an update .pkpass bundle and force an update with a "replace pass with pass".

Comment: NSArray * passArray = [_passLib passes];
    PKPass *onePass = [passArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"pass identifier %@",onePass.passTypeIdentifier);
        
    NSLog(@"pass rewards %@",[onePass localizedValueForFieldKey:@"rewards"]);

    } I am using this code for retrieving the reward field from my pass through Pkpass Library. I am always getting null for that field. But i am able to retrieve the pass identifier? Can you say your view on this error?